# If I beat the Wall of Flesh does it place ALL worlds I have into hardmode?

Tags: terraria

Does defeating the Wall of Flesh make every world I've created go into Hardmode?

If I create a world after defeating the WOF, will it be created in Hardmode?

Answer (score 10):

No.  Hardmode is per world.  When hardmode starts after you defeat the Wall of Flesh, it will only affect the current world, and doesn't affect any others you may have saved or created.

Answer (score -1):

Hardmode is a per-world occurrence. If you kill the WoF in one world, only that world will go into Hardmode.

I know this from experience. Recently, I killed the WoF in my one world, and all of the other worlds (secret seeds or otherwise) stayed in their Pre-Hardmode state.

Comment: Hi EgoWaffles, thanks for your contribution, but note that your answer has already been given. Please read through the existing answers to see if yours would add anything useful to the question. And welcome to Arqade!